# ASP.NET 5: How to run function on singleton after creation?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, dependency-injection

I have an application (a web api) which uses DI. I have a heavy class that will process a lot of text files on startup. It needs about two minutes. I'd like for the application to get going with that as soon as it starts up, rather than when it's first called.

I have read that one should not do any heavy processing in the constructor of DI files, so what's the correct way of doing it? All my class does it provide a string in response to a string. My class unfortunately doesn't support multithreading. How can I make it thread-safe in an easy way? Performance is not a big deal for me. Make sure everything is private and make some kind of token for when it's performing a query?

Edit: I spent some time on it, and here is my Startup class. I made a 'starter' class which receives the MibLibrary class by DI and performs some starting operations on it, that seems to work reasonably well. But I'm really way out of my comfort zone here because I'm not used with DI, so I really wanna learn and take advice of what is best practice, because this will be a production service later on.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();

            services.Configure<Appsettings>(Configuration);
            services.Configure<MibLibrarySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Appsettings.MibLibrarySettings"));
            services.AddSingleton<MibLibStarter>();
            services.AddSingleton<MibLibrary>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MibLibApi", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, MibLibStarter mibLibStarter)
        {
            mibLibStarter.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Create a `IHostedService` and have that handle the singleton on startup

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what you need, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Optionally to using an `IHostedService`, you can also resolve the component from inside the `Startup.Configure` method and call its method on a background thread (but I'd say that using an `IHostedService` is probably more idiomatic).

Comment: Thank you both, @Steven I did what you suggested while waiting for replies to this and I managed to iron out most problems. I'm open to hearing how using the IHostedService is a better solution and rewriting it though!

Comment: @VincentVega, for starters, with IHostedService, you can stop the operation, if the application stops prematurely.